# the probability of 2 people visiting the same hotel on two days

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Suppose everyone behave at random, deciding with probability **0.1** to visit a hotel among **5** hotels on any given day.

> The question is: The probability of the two people  (A and B)  visiting the same hotel on day 1 and day 2 under two conditions respectively as follows:

1. The hotels can be different on different days.

   *My answer is* : $(0.1^2\times\frac{5}{5}\times\frac{1}{5})^2$

   1. $0.1^2$ means the chances of two people visiting a hotel on any given day
   2. $\frac{5}{5}\times\frac{1}{5}$ means the chances of choosing the same hotel. A has 5 hotel choices and B has 1 choice after A has chosen a hotel.The total number of hotels A and B can pick is $5\times5$.
   3. The out square is for 2 days since the event of two people visiting the same hotel on any given day is independent.
2. The hotels must be the same on different days.

   *My answer is* : $(0.1^2\times\frac{5}{5}\times\frac{1}{5})\times(0.1^2\times\frac{1}{5}^2)$

   1. The $\frac{1}{5}^2$ means that they have only 1 choice on the second day since they have already chosen the hotel on the first day.

Am I right?

Comment: Is $\pmb{p}$ a vector of probabilities ? And what exactly do you mean by two people visiting the same hotel on two days ? Is it that there exist two hotels such that two people goes in the first one on the first day and two people (that may be different) goes in the second one on the second day ?

Comment: @P.Quinton I modified the question to make it more clear, but I am not sure if you can understand.

Comment: So what I understand now is that given one person, for every hotel he have $0.1$ chances of going in, and he have $0.5$ of not going in an hotel ? Anyway you should be careful about your total probability, it should be $1$.

Comment: What you gave is not an answer, it is a string of numbers and arithmetic symbols. An answer should include some reasoning, an explanation on why this is the correct value; and of course also the final number, not just a big term. If you write down the reasoning, you should notice your mistakes yourself.

Comment: One person has 0.1 chances of visiting a hotel on any given day, and 0.9 chances not. @P.Quinton